# GPT4All Metal Library Conflict during Embedding on M1 Mac

Tags: metal, langchain, language-model, gpt4all

I am trying to run GPT4All's embedding model on my M1 Macbook with the following code:

```
import json
import numpy as np
from gpt4all import GPT4All, Embed4All

# Load the cleaned JSON data
with open('coursesclean.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Create an index and embeddings array
index = {}
embeddings = []

# Iterate over each course
for course_code, course_info in data.items():
    course_name = course_info['course_name']
    course_desc = course_info['course_desc']

    text = f"{course_name} {course_desc}"

    embedder = Embed4All()
    embeddings_response = embedder.embed(text)
    course_embeddings = np.array(embeddings_response)

    # Store the embeddings in the array
    embeddings.append(course_embeddings)

    # Index the embeddings
    index[course_code] = len(embeddings) - 1

# Convert the embeddings array to a NumPy array
embeddings_array = np.stack(embeddings)

save the index and embeddings array to NumPy files
np.save('embeddings.npy', embeddings_array)
with open('index.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(index, file, indent=2)
```

However, I seem to be running into a Metal library conflict that puts me in an infinite loop of the Found model file statement.

```
Found model file at  /Users/MY_USERNAME/.cache/gpt4all/ggml-all-MiniLM-L6-v2-f16.bin
objc[42338]: Class GGMLMetalClass is implemented in both /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpt4all/llmodel_DO_NOT_MODIFY/build/libreplit-mainline-metal.dylib (0x11eb0c208) and /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpt4all/llmodel_DO_NOT_MODIFY/build/libllamamodel-mainline-metal.dylib (0x11ef38208). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Found model file at  /Users/MY_USERNAME//.cache/gpt4all/ggml-all-MiniLM-L6-v2-f16.bin
Found model file at  /Users/MY_USERNAME//.cache/gpt4all/ggml-all-MiniLM-L6-v2-f16.bin
...
```

I've tried reinstalling GPT4All, cleared the model from cache and tried through Langchain but I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely unrelated to your code.
Check https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all/issues/1233